# I want to backup bootcamp and Macintosh HD hard drive to my external hard drive using Disk Utility. How Can I do that?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, boot-camp

My Macbook pro has got completely messed up. It has the regular Mountain Lion and Windows 8 installed through Bootcamp. I guess some startup file got corrupted and now Mac wouldnt repair even when I am trying to reinstall Mac OSx. It would show me that there was a problem installing Mac OSX. I even tried  to re-set the NVRAM / PRAM, but it still wouldnt work. I guess, the only way left now is to backup both Bootcamp and Macintosh HD to a external hard drive (so that I can save all my data) and then do a complete format of the hard drive and reinstall a fresh copy of Mountain Lion. Can anyone please guide me on how I can mirror the Bootcamp and Macintosh HD to an external hard drive? Please note that I cannot log in to Mac. I can only access Disk utility when I start the computer. Thank you very much for the support. Your help is truly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot to Windows 8? If so, you can use Windows' backup function to backup your bootcamp partition to an external hard drive. If you need to re-install Windows 8, you can simply restore that backup image after booting the Windows 8 installation DVD.

Do you have access to other computers? If so, you can buy a cheap 2.5" external hard drive enclosure from Amazon or eBay and put your MacBook drive in it and let the other computer read the drive using various backup software (a lot of which free).

Hope that helps.

wywong